# dk.brics.automaton gets into infinite looping when given regex "a.b"?

Tags: regex, lexical-analysis, dfa, automaton

I am wondering what metacharacters does `dk.brics.automaton` support.

Does it even not support `.` operator? When I give `a.b` to it, it gets into infinite loop until `Err: OutOfMemory`.

Is there any alternative to get the same purpose as `.`?

If you have ideas of which operators does `dk.brics.automaton` support, please help list them here.

Comment: You must have worked much on dk.brics.automaton . I am new to it and want to use it to compute the number of DFA states , transitions and memory taken by each state.Do you think this tool will help me in achieving these tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the grammar (http://www.brics.dk/automaton/doc/dk/brics/automaton/RegExp.html), that should work.  Perhaps some of your code would help.

Comment: Thanks! It should be my problem. The original version does work well with `.`.